# How do I fill in missing values based on the values in other rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

```
country <- c("USA","UK","Egypt","Brazil","USA", "UK")
continent <- c("North America","Europe","Africa","South America", NA, NA)
data.frame(country, continent)
```

How do I automatically impute those last two NAs based on the previous rows since we know that "USA" goes with "North America" and "UK" goes with "Europe"?

I have a large dataset so it would be super helpful if I could find a quick way to do this in dplyr when there are many NAs.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d1 %>% 
     group_by(country) %>% 
     fill(continent) %>% 
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  country continent    
  <chr>   <chr>        
1 USA     North America
2 UK      Europe       
3 Egypt   Africa       
4 Brazil  South America
5 USA     North America
6 UK      Europe
```

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate the response. Just as a follow-up, how would I input a missing value manually if there isn't a corresponding observation for `continent` and `country`?

Comment: @krmo you can use `complete` to expand the data for missing cases

Comment: How would I do this for a specific row? Say, I wanted to add "Asia" to a row that currently has: "China", NA. Thank you again @akrun!

Comment: @krmo do you have a case where the value is "Asia" for `China` or is it a new entry

Answer (score 2):

We could use `na.locf` from `zoo` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    do(na.locf(.)) %>% 
    arrange(id) %>% 
    select(-id) %>% 
    ungroup
```

Output:

```
  country continent    
  <chr>   <chr>        
1 USA     North America
2 UK      Europe       
3 Egypt   Africa       
4 Brazil  South America
5 USA     North America
6 UK      Europe
```